# Joining large dictionaries by identical keys

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dictionary, defaultdict

I have around 10 huge files that contain python dictionaries like so:

```
    dict1:
    {   
        'PRO-HIS-MET': {
            'A': ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]),
            'B': ([5,2],[6],[8,9]),
            'C': ([3],[4],[7,8])},
        'TRP-MET-GLN': {
            'F': ([-5,-4,1123],[-7,-11,2],[-636,-405])}
    }

    dict2:
    {   
        'PRO-HIS-MET': {
            'J': ([-657], [7,-20,3], [-8,-85,15])}

        'TRP-MET-GLN':{
            'K': ([1,2,3],[4,50,6],[7,80,9]), 
            'L': ([5,20],[60,80],[8,9])}
    }
```

Basically they are all dictionaries of dictionaries. Each file is around 1 GB in size (the above is just an example of the data). Anyway, what I would like to do is join the 10 dictionaries together:

```
    final:
    {
        'PRO-HIS-MET': {
            'A': ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]),
            'B': ([5,2],[6],[8,9]),
            'C': ([3],[4],[7,8])
            'J': ([-657], [7,-20,3], [-8,-85,15])},
        'TRP-MET-GLN': {
            'F': ([-5,-4,1123],[-7,-11,2],[-636,-405])
            'K': ([1,2,3],[4,50,6],[7,80,9]), 
            'L': ([5,20],[60,80],[8,9])}
    }
```

I have tried the following code on small files and it works fine:

```
    import csv
    import collections
    d1 = {}
    d2 = {}
    final = collections.defaultdict(dict)

    for key, val in csv.reader(open('filehere.txt')):
        d1[key] = eval(val)
    for key, val in csv.reader(open('filehere2.txt')):
        d2[key] = eval(val)

    for key in d1:
        final[key].update(d1[key])
    for key in d2:
        final[key].update(d2[key])

    out = csv.writer(open('out.txt', 'w'))
    for k, v in final.items():
        out.writerow([k, v])
```

However if I try that on my 1 GB files I quickly run out of memory by keeping d1 and d2 as well as the final dictionary in memory.

I have a couple ideas:

1. Is there a way where I can just load the keys from the segmented dictionaries, compare those, and if the same ones are found in multiple dictionaries just combine the values?
2. Instead of merging the dictionaries into one huge file (which will probably give me memory headaches in the future), how can I make many separate files that contain all the values for one key after merging data? For example, for the above data I would just have:

   ```
   pro-his-met.txt:
   'PRO-HIS-MET': {
       'A': ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]),
       'B': ([5,2],[6],[8,9]),
       'C': ([3],[4],[7,8])
       'J': ([-657], [7,-20,3], [-8,-85,15])}
   trp-met-gln.txt:
   'TRP-MET-GLN': {
       'F': ([-5,-4,1123],[-7,-11,2],[-636,-405])
       'K': ([1,2,3],[4,50,6],[7,80,9]), 
       'L': ([5,20],[60,80],[8,9])}
   ```

I don't have too much programming experience as a biologist (you may have guessed the above data represents a bioinformatics problem) so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a database system?  It sounds like what you have is an awful lot of data to be manipulating in this manner.

Comment: Mostly the reason is my inexperience with any kind of database. What do you suggest I use to convert a python dictionary to a db?

Comment: The fact that you use `eval` makes it rather difficult to have a lazy solution. Do as @Voo says and use a a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shelve` module is a very easy-to-use database for Python. It's nowhere near as powerful as a real database (for that, see @Voo's answer), but it will do the trick for manipulating large dictionaries.

First, create shelves from your dictionaries:

```
import shelve
s = shelve.open('filehere.db', flag='n', protocol=-1, writeback=False)
for key, val in csv.reader(open('filehere.txt')):
    s[key] = eval(val)
s.close()
```

Now that you've shelved everything neatly, you can operate on the dictionaries efficiently:

```
import shelve
import itertools
s = shelve.open('final.db', flag='c', protocol=-1, writeback=False)
s1 = shelve.open('file1.db', flag='r')
s2 = shelve.open('file2.db', flag='r')
for key, val in itertools.chain(s1.iteritems(), s2.iteritems()):
    d = s.get(key, {})
    d.update(val)
    s[key] = d # force write
s.close()
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks like a good short term solution for the moment. I'll definitely have to learn a thing or two about databases for the future.

Comment: Interesting module there, will keep in mind for future reference, that could certainly come in handy.

Comment: @nneonneo, I tried a quick implementation of this but updating the values doesn't seem to work. I get a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'" error since it seems like it's updating a key that doesn't exist. I did use a defaultdict before for this problem but I'm not sure how to proceed here, any ideas?

Comment: That's my fault. `update` returns `None`. I fixed the code, try it now.

Comment: @nneonneo -- awesome. Does exactly what I need for now. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Personally this sounds like the archetype of a problem databases were invented to solve. Yes you can solve this yourself with keeping files around and for performance optimizations map them into memory and let the OS handle the swapping, etc. but this is really complicated and hard to do really good.

Why go through all this effort if you can let a DB - into which millions of man-hours of have been put - handle it? That will be more efficient and as an added benefit much easier to query for information.

I've seen Oracle DBs storing much more than 10 GB of data without any problems, I'm sure postgre will handle this just as well.. the nice thing is if you use an ORM you can abstract those nitty gritty details away and worry about them later if it gets necessary.

Also while bioinformatics isn't my speciality I'm pretty sure there are specific solutions tailored to bioinformatics around - maybe one of them would be the perfect fit?

Comment: Indeed that sounds like what I should be doing. I have little experience with databases, what do you suggest I use? Let me try to give a little background as well: the original data is a big 6 GB dictionary that was generated using BioPython code, which was re-sorted to the information above. That's the reason I've been sticking to these data structures but I would be glad to learn something new.

Comment: @deckardk Personally I would start by looking at some tutorials for [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) an Object-relational mapping (ORM) that abstracts most of the database mojo away from you. For your database you probably want to use PostgreSQL instead of sqlite which is used for the tutorial though (but since those details are abstracted away you can easily start with sqlite for simplicity and if you notice that the performance isn't good enough change to Postgre later).

Comment: Thanks @Voo. I will take a look at the tutorials and try to learn something new about databases :)

Answer (score 0):

This concept should work.

I would consider to do multiple passes on the file where each time you do a portion of keys. and save that result.

Eg. if you create a list of the unique first characters of all the keys in one pass and then process each of thoses passes to new output files. If it was simple alphabetic data the logical choice would be a loop with each letter of the alphabet.

Eg. in the "p" pass you would process 'PRO-HIS-MET'

Then you would combine all the results from all the files at the end.

If you were a developer, the Database idea in the previous answer is probably the best approach if you can handle that kind of interaction. That idea entails creating a 2 level structure where you insert and update the records then query the result with an SQL statement.

Comment: Making the filesystem solution even close to scalable and efficient, probably involves memory mapping files into the address space and letting the OS worry about swapping. *Much* more complicated than a trivial DB setup for which there are millions of tutorials around.

Comment: The poster is not a developer (implies he has zero DB skills) I suggested an approach he may be capable of based on the fact he has the scripting skills. I do beleive the DB solution is the best approach, as noted in the posting.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing I'm just saying that the post is working in bioinformatics which means the 10GB is probably a small lower bound for the amount of data he'll get and implementing the given problem even somewhat efficiently with the FS is a hell of a lot more complicated than reading a ORM tutorial. Hell it'd take an experienced developer a day or so to come up with something sensible.